# Contentful This is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

[image]

I have the content model with one field as a JSON object.
When I write an array inside this field I get `This is not valid JSON`.

[image]

Also in another screenshot, as you can see on Contentful Page it shows the error as mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Single quotes aren’t allowed in json.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer @codemonkey. Even though I have tried with " " quotes but issue remain as it was.

Comment: https://www.json.org/

Comment: Show a screenshot with an invalid json using regular quotes.

Comment: once again thanks @codemonkey I have added the new screenshot in the very first of this question please you may check it.

Comment: Could you please provide the _JSON_ as actual text so that others can validate it?

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not allow a comma after the last element in an array:

Good:

```js
let string = '["Hello","Folks"]';
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

Bad:

```js
let string = '["Hello","Folks",]'; // comma after "Folks"
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

Comment: Voila ..! You are 101% right the problem was same as you mentioned not to add the , comma after the last element. You are great Man.! Thank you so much for helping me.